# Possible ammonia anomaly?

Tags: acid-base

In class we have learned that an acid + a base/alkali --> salt + water.

For example:

> hydrochloric acid + sodium hydroxide --> sodium chloride + water

However, when I try the same thing with ammonia, I get something like the following:

> hydrochloric acid + ammonia--> ammonium chloride

Since there is no oxygen present on the left side, I cannot possibly put water as an extra reagent on the right. However, doesn't this contradict the fact that this type of reaction **always** forms *extra*
water? (I do realize there will always be water present, as either the acid and/or the base are in aqueous solution, but I'm talking about the formation of new water) Is this an anomaly of ammonia, or is there something fundamentally wrong about my equations?

Answer (score 4):

> Is this an anomaly of ammonia, or is there something fundamentally wrong about my equations?

Fundamentally wrong would be a bit harsh ;)

But notice that the reaction

$$\ce{HCl + NaOH -> NaCl + H2O}$$

is just a special case of a general reaction between an acid and a base. It is special in the sense that the base on the left side of the equation is a hydroxide.

The more general equation for this kind of reaction is

$$\ce{HA + B -> A- + HB+}$$

With other words, the *Brønsted-Lowry* acid donates a proton to the base. As a result, the acid $\ce{HA}$ is converted to its corresponding base $\ce{A-}$ while the base $\ce{B}$ is converted to its corresponding acid $\ce{HB+}$.

In your first equation, $\ce{OH-}$ is the base, while $\ce{H2O}$ is its corresponding acid.